# Parse OSM PBF in AWS Lambda and S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openstreetmap, aws-lambda

I'm working on a small project and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var through = require('through2');
var parseOSM = require('osm-pbf-parser');

var https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var request = https.get("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testing-osm/indianapolis_extract.osm.pbf", function(response) {
        var osm = parseOSM();
        fs.createReadStream(response)
        .pipe(osm)
        .pipe(through.obj(function (items, enc, next) {
            items.forEach(function (item) {
                console.log('item=', item);
        });
        next();
    }))
;
    });
};
```

I used NPM to download fs, through2, https, and osm-pbf-parser libraries. When I tried to run it (no special input parameters, just run it), I get the following:

```
START RequestId: 0a60d8ad-c275-11e6-8d63-f141d0387b78 Version: $LATEST
2016-12-15T03:17:42.860Z    0a60d8ad-c275-11e6-8d63-f141d0387b78    TypeError: path must be a string
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:540:11)
    at ReadStream.open (fs.js:1677:6)
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1664:10)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1612:10)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:12:6)
```

I'm not sure if anyone out there has done this before but I'm wanting to get an OSM PBF file from a URL, load it into Lambda, and parse it. I don't need help with anything other than getting it to read the contents of an file.osm.pbf file.

Any help on this is highly appreciated